# Eigen Sparse LU solver

Tags: c++, c++17, eigen

I am using the Eigen library in C++ for solving sparse linear equations: Ax=b where, A is a square sparse matrix and b is a rectangular sparse matrix. I have multiple instances of the A matrices and each one has multiple right hand sides b. Hence, I want to factorize all the A matrices once and store them followed by solution for each A with each b.

I tried to use the C++ vector for storing all the solvers. This is a sample code I have written:

```
vector<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> A;
//fill in all A matrices

vector<Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>> solver_A;

Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;

for (int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
    solver.analyzePattern(A[i]); 
    solver.factorize(A[i]);      
    solver_A.push_back(solver);
}

//Later, solver_A entries are to be used to solve for various right hand sides
```

I am using 3.3.7 version of Eigen and compiling in linux with gcc compiler and c++17 standard. I am getting the following compilation error due to the `solver_A.push_back(solver)` line:

```
<pre>/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘<b>void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator&lt;_Tp&gt;::construct(_Up*, _Args&amp;&amp; ...) [with _Up = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;; _Args = {const Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double, 0, int&gt;, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering&lt;int&gt; &gt;&amp;}; _Tp = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;]</b>’:
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:</b>   required from ‘<b>static void std::allocator_traits&lt;std::allocator&lt;_CharT&gt; &gt;::construct(std::allocator_traits&lt;std::allocator&lt;_CharT&gt; &gt;::allocator_type&amp;, _Up*, _Args&amp;&amp; ...) [with _Up = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;; _Args = {const Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double, 0, int&gt;, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering&lt;int&gt; &gt;&amp;}; _Tp = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;; std::allocator_traits&lt;std::allocator&lt;_CharT&gt; &gt;::allocator_type = std::allocator&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt; &gt;]</b>’
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:943:30:</b>   required from ‘<b>void std::vector&lt;_Tp, _Alloc&gt;::push_back(const value_type&amp;) [with _Tp = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;; _Alloc = std::allocator&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt; &gt;; std::vector&lt;_Tp, _Alloc&gt;::value_type = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;]</b>’
<b>header_files/coefficient_computations.cpp:476:51:</b>   required from here
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4:</b> <font color="#EF2929"><b>error: </b></font>‘Eigen::SparseLU&lt;_MatrixType, _OrderingType&gt;::SparseLU(const Eigen::SparseLU&lt;_MatrixType, _OrderingType&gt;&amp;) [with _MatrixType = Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt;; _O<b>rderingType = Eigen::COLAMDOrdering&lt;int&gt;]</b>’ is private within this context
  { <font color="#EF2929"><b>::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward&lt;_Args&gt;(__args)...)</b></font>; }
    <font color="#EF2929"><b>^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
In file included from <b>../Eigen_3_3_7/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/SparseLU:44:0</b>,
                 from <b>../Eigen_3_3_7/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/Sparse:31</b>,
                 from <b>../Eigen_3_3_7/unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra:13</b>,
                 from <b>header_files/general_functions.hpp:17</b>,
                 from <b>header_files/coefficient_computations.hpp:17</b>,
                 from <b>header_files/coefficient_computations.cpp:2</b>:
<b>../Eigen_3_3_7/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/src/SparseLU/SparseLU.h:393:5:</b> <font color="#34E2E2"><b>note: </b></font>declared private here
     <font color="#34E2E2"><b>SparseLU</b></font> (const SparseLU&amp; );
     <font color="#34E2E2"><b>^~~~~~~~</b></font>
In file included from <b>/usr/include/c++/7/vector:62:0</b>,
                 from <b>header_files/coefficient_computations.hpp:13</b>,
                 from <b>header_files/coefficient_computations.cpp:2</b>:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘<b>void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&amp;&amp; ...) [with _T1 = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;; _Args = {Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double, 0, int&gt;, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering&lt;int&gt; &gt;}]</b>’:
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:</b>   required from ‘<b>static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy&lt;_TrivialValueTypes&gt;::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*&gt;; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]</b>’
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:</b>   required from ‘<b>_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*&gt;; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*]</b>’
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:</b>   required from ‘<b>_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator&lt;_Tp&gt;&amp;) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*&gt;; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*; _Tp = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;]</b>’
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:311:2:</b>   required from ‘<b>_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&amp;) [with _InputIterator = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*; _Allocator = std::allocator&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt; &gt;]</b>’
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/bits/vector.tcc:426:6:</b>   required from ‘<b>void std::vector&lt;_Tp, _Alloc&gt;::_M_realloc_insert(std::vector&lt;_Tp, _Alloc&gt;::iterator, _Args&amp;&amp; ...) [with _Args = {const Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double, 0, int&gt;, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering&lt;int&gt; &gt;&amp;}; _Tp = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;; _Alloc = std::allocator&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt; &gt;; std::vector&lt;_Tp, _Alloc&gt;::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*, std::vector&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt; &gt; &gt;; typename std::_Vector_base&lt;_Tp, _Alloc&gt;::pointer = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;*]</b>’
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:948:21:</b>   required from ‘<b>void std::vector&lt;_Tp, _Alloc&gt;::push_back(const value_type&amp;) [with _Tp = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;; _Alloc = std::allocator&lt;Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt; &gt;; std::vector&lt;_Tp, _Alloc&gt;::value_type = Eigen::SparseLU&lt;Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt; &gt;]</b>’
<b>header_files/coefficient_computations.cpp:476:51:</b>   required from here
<b>/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7:</b> <font color="#EF2929"><b>error: </b></font>‘Eigen::SparseLU&lt;_MatrixType, _OrderingType&gt;::SparseLU(const Eigen::SparseLU&lt;_MatrixType, _OrderingType&gt;&amp;) [with _MatrixType = Eigen::SparseMatrix&lt;double&gt;; _O<b>rderingType = Eigen::COLAMDOrdering&lt;int&gt;]</b>’ is private within this context
     { <font color="#EF2929"><b>::new(static_cast&lt;void*&gt;(__p)) _T1(std::forward&lt;_Args&gt;(__args)...)</b></font>; }
       <font color="#EF2929"><b>^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~</b></font>
In file included from <b>../Eigen_3_3_7/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/SparseLU:44:0</b>,
                 from <b>../Eigen_3_3_7/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/Sparse:31</b>,
                 from <b>../Eigen_3_3_7/unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra:13</b>,
                 from <b>header_files/general_functions.hpp:17</b>,
                 from <b>header_files/coefficient_computations.hpp:17</b>,
                 from <b>header_files/coefficient_computations.cpp:2</b>:
<b>../Eigen_3_3_7/unsupported/Eigen/../../Eigen/src/SparseLU/SparseLU.h:393:5:</b> <font color="#34E2E2"><b>note: </b></font>declared private here
     <font color="#34E2E2"><b>SparseLU</b></font> (const SparseLU&amp; );
     <font color="#34E2E2"><b>^~~~~~~~</b></font>
</pre>
```

The compilation is successful if the line "solver_A.push_back(solver)" is commented. Any help is appreciated either to fix this issue or with alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

`vector::push_back` requires the vector elements to be either copy or move constructible. `SparseLU` is neither of both because it has a private copy constructor (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/SparseLU_8h_source.html):

> ```
> private:
> // Disable copy constructor 
>  SparseLU (const SparseLU& );
> ```

You can work around that in a number of ways. For example, by constructing the vector of solvers with the appropriate size so that it would need not to grow dynamically (https://godbolt.org/z/vS85P8):

```
vector<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> A;

vector<Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>> solver_A(A.size());

for (int i=0;i<A.size();i++) {
  solver_A[i].analyzePattern(A[i]); 
  solver_A[i].factorize(A[i]);
  }
```

If that’s not possible, another option would be to wrap your solvers into a movable type, for example a `std::unique_ptr<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>`.

As a side note, you can use `compute` instead of `analyzePattern` and then `factorize`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `std::deque` together with the `emplace_back` method.
Note that the same is not possible with `std::vector` because here the `vector::emplace_back` may move the existing elements. `deque::emplace_back` doesn't need to do this.

I don't know, what algorithm you are implementing but I had a similar problem and thought I needed to store the solvers. In my case it was instead possible to use the solvers one after another (and never again for the same matrix), so I could use one solver instead of a vector. That's probably a better way if it is possible as it is less heavy on memory, as each solver demands 500 bytes on the stack alone.